# Import projects with links using adobe xd

Tags: adobe-xd

I recently started using adobe XD and I got a link to a project that I am not a coworker of. But I still would like to import this project to make changes and have all the data available. So now I wonder how I can get the project into my adobe XD app on my pc with only the link?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to edit the XD file from a shared link unless the one whom sent it to you makes it a coediting link (invites you to the cloud document itself), or sends you the actual XD file.

Comment: I do not want to edit the actual file but create a copy of it and then continue working on it. Is this possible?